# Question about the curl of a vector field.

Tags: calculus, vectors, partial-derivative, vector-fields

When calculating the curl of a vector field $\vec{F}=M(x,y)\vec{i}+N(x,y)\vec{j}$ why does difference of the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}$ tell me if the vector field is rotating or not? I don't understand the meaning behind this difference.

Comment: One direction is automatic from equality of mixed second partials, the other is much more subtle involving assumptions on the domain (simple connectivity, e.g.).

Comment: As is, the question is really too broad to be answered, at least without some more details on what's confusing.  Most calculus textbooks contain the details on this:  what part don't you understand?

Comment: @Randall why the difference of partial derivatives imply a rotation in the field?

Comment: What does "rotation in the field" mean to you?

Comment: @Randall From my understanding and from what i've seen it means that the vectors in the vector field either change direction or cause a torque.

Comment: I think that's your issue.  That's not really a precise, mathematical notion to play with.  There are plenty of irrotational and rotational fields whose vectors "change direction."

Comment: A precise physical interpretation arises from Stoke's theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics).

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too. There is a good strategy to tackle this out:

Let $\vec{F}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a vector field, of the form (this is the standard form of  bidimensional vector fields in physics):
$$\vec{F}(x,y)=(a(x,y),b(x,y),c(x,y))$$
Where $\{a,b,c\}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are functions of two variables to the real numbers. This only means that for every point in the cartesian plane $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, there exists a vector $\vec{v}$ in the vector space $V(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that:
$$\vec{v}=(a,b,c)$$
Where $a,b,c$ are real numbers given by the functions ($c$ is typically zero). $\nabla$ is a dummy vector of $V(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that
$$\nabla=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},0)$$
($\nabla$ would have also a partial derivative with respect to $z$ if the original vector field were $\vec{F}:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, instead of $\vec{F}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$).

$\nabla$ is not a real vector, but the linear transformations associated with it function the same way a real vector would:
$$\nabla\cdot\vec{v}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}a+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}b+0$$
And $\nabla\cdot\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}$. Also
$$\vec{w}=\nabla\times\vec{v}=(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}c,-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}c,\frac{\partial}{\partial x}b-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}a)$$
Where $\vec{w}\in V(\mathbb{R}^3)$

Note that if $\vec{F}$ has no $c$ component, then $\vec{w}=(0,0,\frac{\partial}{\partial x}b-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}a)$ has no $\hat{i}$ or $\hat{j}$ components. This is expected, as the cross product is supposed to be orthogonal to both multiplied vectors. It is probable that you do not understand some of these things. If you don't, you will  need more abstract linear algebra to get this post.